# Azure CDN - redirect from *.azurewebsites.net to cdn generate ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn, azure-custom-domain

I have a website on azure. Then I've created a CDN. I've a custom domain to my cdn.
Now I have added this configuration on my website:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>        
      <rule name="RedirectToDomain" stopProcessing="true"  patternSyntax="Wildcard">
        <match url="*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mysite-app-net47-test-westeu.azurewebsites.net" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.mysite.com/{R:0}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  ...
</system.webServer>
```

where `https://test.mysite.com/` is a custom domain of my cdn :

[image]

But now I get this error:

[image]

I deleted cookies, I purge the cache... but I have not solved. I have tried to check redirect via `redirect path` and i get this:

(first time):

[image]

and then always:

[image]

Here the request traced with fiddler... both look likes equal:

[image]

The question seems get changed instead (the second is the request toward the cdn):

[image]

How can I solve?

Thank you

Comment: I guess the CDN is making a request through the Azure websites domain name, which returns a 301 -> which the CDN returns to the user -> repeat. Maybe there is some header that the CDN applies that you could check for here? So you don't redirect if it's the CDN?

Comment: @juunas I have edited the question... yes it seems there is a little difference in the header... so, what can I check to block redirect?

Comment: Those look like _response_ headers that you receive. I mean the CDN service is making an HTTP request to your Web App and it might include a _request_ header that would allow you to filter those requests. You could temporarily remove the redirect config and then try to see if you can log request headers received by your app.

Comment: @juunas I have updated again the question

Comment: this is the only difference I see between requests: `:authority: test.xxx.com` and `:authority: xxx-app-net47-test-westeu.azurewebsites.net`

Answer (score 0):

You can append a request header in CDN Rules engine and then add a condition of {HTTP_headername} on your app service web.config.

Azure CDN Endpoint > Rules engine > in global rule Add action Modify Request Header > Action: Append

Then in your rule condition:

```
<add input="{HTTP_headerName}" pattern="Header Value" negate="true" />
```