# How to block crawling of the origin when Azure CDN is configured

Tags: azure, web-crawler, seo, azure-cdn, azure-custom-domain

something is not clear using Azure CDN.
I explain step by step what I have done since my website has been created. Call my website `www.mypublicwebsite.com`. So:

1. I created a web app on Azure. The website has the following url: `https://mypublicwebsite.azurewebsites.net`;
2. I created a custom domain `www.mypublicwebsite.com`
3. I redirected all the request from `https://mypublicwebsite.azurewebsites.net` to `www.mypublicwebsite.com`. So I solved the problem of duplicated contents for crawlers.

Everything is fine. Then, I decided to create CDN, according the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-overview). Here the confusion starts.

4. I created the CDN profile
5. I created the  endpoint. The endpoint has a new url `https://mypublicwebsite.azureedge.net`
6. I deleted the custom domain from web app;
7. I created the custom domain in cdn profile.

So the current state is this:

[image]

This situation is really problematic for SEO!! It cannot be the correct configuration. My contents are triplicated.
I partially solved the situation:

8. I redirected all the request from `https://mypublicwebsite.azureedge.net` to `www.mypublicwebsite.com`. So I solved the problem of duplicated content for crawlers.

But crawler (and perhaps users?) can still navigate the origin web site. I have been looking for different solutions:

- Make a redirect from `https://mypublicwebsite.azurewebsites.net` to `www.mypublicwebsite.com`. But this create a [infinite redirects loop between the CDN and the origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66472075/azure-cdn-redirect-from-azurewebsites-net-to-cdn-generate-err-too-many-redir?noredirect=1#comment117515230_66472075).
- Try to hide the origin, but how?

I am honestly starting thinking this is not the correct way to manage cdn.
Can anyone help me please?

Thank you